# groovy Release no longer has a Release file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When ever I tried to run this command "sudo-apt update" I get following errors:

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don't understand all these issue most of them has "groovy Release no longer has a Release file." My question, what is the reasons for these issues and how can I fix them. I tried some solutions like change file in '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list' but its not fixing the issue infact its creating more issues.

Comment: Might be better on the Unix / Linux stack.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/rs0l06/apt_update_is_broken_in_popos_for_some_reason/